# How do I implement WCF with Silverlight, supporting both ASP.NET session state and SSL?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, session-state

We have a Silverlight intranet application using old web services, and I've been tasked with adding support for SSL. To do this I was planning to ditch the old web services and replace them with a new WCF service.

I also needed to get rid of the old web references and build the proxy dynamically as well (because the endpoint will vary), and found this useful article which outlines how to build dynamic proxies http://sonyarouje.com/2010/10/01/proxy-less-silverlight-wcf-communication.

I now have that working (although I now need to work out how to call a method that has parameters) but I've just discovered that (a) Silverlight only supports BasicHttpBinding (i.e. not ws), and (b) BasicHttpBinding does not support session state.

Our application currently uses session to keep track of and queue up requests through our singleton data access layer. The only thing I can think of doing at the moment is to write my own implementation of session - but I was wondering if there's a better solution that I'm missing, hence this post.

So basically, is there a 'best practice' approach that supports Silverlight, WCF, session state and SSL, or am I right to go ahead and replace session with my own equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've mixed WCF session with ASP.NET Sessions. WCF Session and ASP.NET sessions are completely different. 
In your case, to enable ASP.NET state in WCF service, you'd just require to enable ASP.NET Compatibility Mode on service,

Please find a very good blog on the same by wenlong,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx

HTH,
Amit

Comment: Wow. You just made my day! After reading that BasicHttpBinding did not support session, and finding that HttpContext.Current was null, I thought that was that. Just added the web.config element and the attribute, and now I have my session back - thank you so much!